# На смартфоне почему-то не появляется чат к прямой трансляции

Tags: javascript, youtube

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=hHW1oY26kxQ&amp;embed_domain=example.com" style="width: 35%; height: 100%; border: none;"></iframe>
```

Вывел на сайте прямую трансляцию и комментарии к ней, на компьютере все работает, но на смартфоне почему-то не появляется чат и в консоли выдает ошибку:

```
 live_chat:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'whenReady' of undefined
    at live_chat:34
    at live_chat:34
(anonymous) @ live_chat:34
(anonymous) @ live_chat:34"
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось YouTube запрещает выводить чат в мобильных браузерах